# Symfony: why is my main page example.com/web instead of example.com (as it should be?)

Tags: deployment, symfony1, url-routing

My directory tree looks something like this:

```
public_html
  example.com(containing symfony files)
    lib
    web
    app 
    etc...
  example.net
  example1.com
  example1.net
```

When I access my site via example.com it just shows my directory tree under the folder example.com, instead of routing to my actual homepage. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place all files (except the `web` directory) in the directory directly above the `web` directory.
Then create a symlink `public_html` to your `web` directory, or add the files to your `public_html`, and then in your `ProjectConfiguration` call `$this->setWebDir(realpath('../public_html'));`