# open link redirect to page with id working on doctrine

Tags: php, redirect, symfony1, hyperlink

I didn't know how to ask professional so if topic is wrong, please correct it.

My problem is quite complicated. I was training on symfony webpage how to generate form and then send this data to another page.

But now i would like do something different. I would like create page xyzSuccess.php. 
Then generate 29 links on this page. Each links would have its own number. 
Each link would redirect to the same page. For example numberSuccess.php. After that, this site would give me data of the number which i clicked.

I will show the example :)

Page xyzSuccess.php have links, the third one is http://localhost:8080/web/number?nr=3

I click on it and i go to numberSuccess.php, the page give me number 3

After the page got number, also take from any datafile information under that number 3 ( i don't know, maybe any file wchich can store symfony / array somewhere?.)

I dont know how to do this, i don't want use any database eq. *sql

So far i created only page xyz.php which use php for loop. I see that action.class.php would work with it if i would use submit button, but i really dont have any idea how make  this working with links. And... that problem with storing data :( maybe create file in lib/form ?

---

corrected the link to page (deleted success which used only in templates), guy under is right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're talking about URL's like `/web/numberSuccess`... That probably means you've misconfigured the root. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383888/symfony-why-is-my-main-page-example-com-web-instead-of-example-com-as-it-should), asked today.

Then it's common to give your actions names like `number`, and then in you're actions file you have the `executeNumber` action, which then renders the `numberSuccess` template. So you shouldn't include the `Success` in the action name/URL.

Then, your question:
What I would do, if you don't want to use a database:

- Create a file `links.txt` in your `/data` directory, and on every line create an url, followed by a space and then the title of your link.
- In your list action open the this file using `file_get_contents()`, explode it on the newline-character, and assign this array to the view.
- In your view loop through the array, use the array index as your `number`, and explode each item on the first space, so you can display the title.
- In the view action your open and explode the links file again, and now you can pointer directly to the index, explode again and you have the URL.